# How to enable PHP in Apache on Linux Fedora?

Tags: php, linux, apache, fedora

The title pretty much sums it up. I'm running **Fedora 18 64-bit** with Apache installed through 'httpd'. I have my Apache running just fine but my PHP doesn't seem to work. I'm fairly certain I do have it installed on my machine (new to Linux).

I created a 'test.php' file in my `/var/www/html/` directory containing the code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` But it's not displaying the way it should, it's just printing out the text to my browser.

So I'm of the idea that PHP isn't set up in my Apache configuration or something. Can someone shed some light on this and have some suggestions on how to go about to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Edit, this is my httpd.config file:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
   AllowOverride None    
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
   DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
   Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

   <IfModule logio_module>
     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
   </IfModule>

   CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
   TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
   AddType application/x-compress .Z
   AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
   AddType text/html .shtml
   AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 8):

1. `yum install php`
2. Restart apache.
3. Try again.

PHP Needs to be installed itself. Its not an apache module to simply enable without first installing PHP.

Comment: Panky - I did install PHP, like I said its just not working. I restarted my machine and server multiple times without getting it to work.

Comment: Panky - I tried removing and re-installing httpd and php. However do get a "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.". I have added my httpd.conf file to my question :)

Answer (score 8):

You May have some Problem One Of Them is You didn't define ".php" index for Apache

like This

```
<IfModule mime_module>
   AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>
```

see this tutorial [install Apache and php](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

and [install Apache and php](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-18-lamp)

Comment: Thanks Mohammand, and you define this in your httpd.conf file?

Comment: see This tutorial For Manual Config Apache for PHP [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) I hope Help You for More help I Must See Apache conf

Comment: I'll update my question with my config file. Also I reinstalled httpd and php. But when I go to localhost now I get this error "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Comment: in This conf that You send Apache not config for php maybe it is Down in Include conf see them if you didn't find conf for php That mean you must conf Your Apache.and "HTTP Error 500 " error is for Wrong Conf code for more Detail You must Run httpd On terminal and check log

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by re-installing httpd & php both. Then php file was executing.

Comment: What a mission! Thanks though, I'll try that.

Comment: @Sawan Koradia - I tried it yet another time. But this time when I hit localhost I get this error: "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Answer (score 1):

Much has changed since this original question and its answers appeared.  As of Fedora 32 and Apache (httpd) 2.4.46,

> mod_php is deprecated as FPM is now used by default with httpd in
> event mode.  mod_php is only used when explicitly enabled or httpd
> switch to prefork mode

([sic] from `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`)

In other words, mod_php is no longer enabled; if you want to use PHP from Apache under Fedora, install php-fpm and it is enabled as the handler of *.php files by default.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, PHP is installed as a package, but interpreted through a module for apache: viz; mod_php. That is a bit of conjecture, I just discovered it for a way to embed HTML.