# All of my PHP code coming as comments in HTML

Tags: php, html

This is my code where I intend to handle the PHP form data on the same page.
However the PHP script doesn't get executed and instead all PHP code is rendered as comments when inspected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php // php code ?>
//html code
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="text" required name="username" placeholder="Username" class="forminput">
    <br>
    <span><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="forminput">
</body>
</html>
```

How can I execute the php script in browser? All files are in root directory.

Comment: It might be due to the browser not being configured correctly - without more info, it's difficult to be precise.. If other php scripts work fine, then this *isnt* the answer, but if all php scripts act the same, then it probably is :) . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660125/how-to-enable-php-in-apache-on-linux-fedora

Comment: I hope the extension of file is .php

Comment: Obviously (or maybe not) I didn't mean browser, I meant web server (apache/nginx/whatever).. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: best explanation for the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: What is the file extension ? Is it .html or .php ?

Comment: Hey, apparently the ' PHP mcrypt ' module was not installed!

Answer (score 3):

You possibly need a [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) server to execute your php code even the file extension you have given as .html.
If your file contain the php code it will need a web server(XAMPP) to execute the process.

Hope this tutorial will help you out with [Use XAMPP to run php program](http://www.fayazmiraz.com/how-to-run-your-first-php-code/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute PHP code in the browser. You need a server that can handle PHP. I suggest you start with an all in one LAMP stack that supports PHP out of the box.

Try this one:

[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)